Is aws emr-containers create-virtual-cluster command asynchronous or synchronous?
I need to know whether the aws emr-containers create-virtual-cluster cli is synchronous or asynchronous. That is when the user receives the response after issuing this aws cli command is the virtual cluster already created (synchronous) or is the creation in progress (asynchronous)?
I have not been able to find an answer in the AWS documentation.
When I issue a create-virtual-cluster and then a describe-virtual-cluster to check it status it usually returns a response that includes a RUNNING state. But this may not be a definitive answer since it could be asynchronous but be executed fast so that the RUNNING state takes effect "immediately". In this scenario, if it is asynchronous, a network delay/hiccup could produce a scenario in which the creation takes a longer time.
